# Can anyone tell me why this where clause is not giving me the result?

Tags: android, sqlite, where-clause

I am trying to retrieve a value from a SQLite Database. My query works fine when I use the following:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM savedlocation WHERE latitude="+lat;
```

But It doesn't work when I use the following query:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM savedlocation WHERE latitude="+lat+"AND longitude="+lon;
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this query?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Missing space before `AND`:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM savedlocation WHERE latitude="+lat+" AND longitude="+lon; 
//                                                                      ^ here
```